# Vue Js + Laravel Loop array that is the same Chatroom once only

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

So I'm making a Chat app and i need to have a recent chat's, But i want it to loop once every chatroom only.

> Vue js Template

```
<template>
 <div>
    <div class="chats" v-for="recentchat in recentchats" v- 
      bind:key="recentchat.id">

       <h1>{{recentchat.username}} </h1>

   </div>   
 </div>
```

> Vue script

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: [ 'user_id' ],
        data() {
            return {
            recentchats: [],
            recentchat: {
               id: '',
                message: '',
                 chatroom_id: '',
                   user_id: '',
                    username: '',
                      profile_image: '',
                        receiver_id: '',
                          created_at: '',
                            updated_at: '',
            }

         }

        },
        created() {
            this.fetchrecentchats();
        },
        methods: {
             fetchrecentchats(){
                 fetch('/api/fetchrecentchats/' +this.user_id)
                 .then(res => res.json())
                 .then(res => {
                     console.log(res);
                     this.recentchats = res.data
                 });
             },
        },  
        mounted() {
            console.log('Recent Chat mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Right now if i loop the username it's looping a user more than once (ex. jacob loops 4 times because he messaged me 4 times ) i jacob to be looped once only . Is there another way to do this? this is Laravel + Vue js. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the API return? Then handle the response in you API co troller if you want just 1 reply.

Comment: @ChristopherDosin it returns all the messages that is sent to me

Comment: @ChristopherDosin how can i do that? can i still get other messages from other chatroom id?

Comment: Can you show us the controller code, and for jacob you want to show only one message or what exactly ?

Comment: You should pull jacob out of your recentchats array then display it outside of your v-for loop

Comment: @Cedrick Next to the "insert image" button in the editor, there is the "insert code" button. Another option would be a working example on https://codesandbox.io
But thats of course only for the frontend. How does your backend controller looks like?